# Do high power (W) elecron beams traveling through air have the same "blooming effect" as high power laser beams?

Tags: optics, electrons, laser, scattering, plasma-physics

So I am talking about an electron beam where the electrons have sufficient velocity and the beam is intense enough (for example, beam power of at least 1 megawatt) to produce enough energy to ionize air into plasma.  Does the ensuing plasma scatter the beam electrons in a similar fashion that it scatters laser light (of high enough intensity to ionize air)?

Answer (score -1):

in my experience with a 1.5 million volt electron beam firing into air, the beam blooms outward and its extent can be traced by the blue glow of ionization.

Comment: Do you have any citations of experiments involving high voltage electron beams beam fired into air?

Comment: @savedbyzero, no. I have my own first-person experiences operating a 1.5MeV electron beam device at Raychem Inc. in redwood city, CA in 1976

Comment: @savedbyzero, why the downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote your answer. Someone else did.